# How to fix Blender Bug, "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction"

Tags: keyframes

Initially, with the issue, I couldn't move or manipulate the object in any way except with the hotkeys like g and r, and then I found the problem. In the log for blender, it kept spamming the message: "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction". I tried performing a full factory reset by reinstalling blender and then loading factory settings in preferences but the issue continued. I have tried adding keyframes to see if that would help but to no avail.
[image: The nightmarish log I'm seeing]

It has begun to lag the blender file to the point where it is dragging about my desktop at 2 frames per second. I'm pretty desperate so any help would be greatly appreciated.

If there is any more information that I can provide that may help a solution surface further I will post it here.

Comment: I don't know why, I don't know how. But I reset my entire PC and reopened blender in an entirely new application and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the layer of the grease pencil is selected (it will turn green) the time marker will snap to the keys in the active layer (the up and down arrow will take you to next and previous frame.

The Keys don't have to be selected. The layer has to have the green high light. You can also select more than one layer in order to flip between multi layer keys.