# Can't scale any object ("No more keyframes to jump to..." error)

Tags: mesh, transforms

Doesn’t let me scale anything across any axis every time I try to it just tells me “no more keyframes to jump to in this direction ”and I just had this issue today already tried re-installing blender

Comment: u also can't scale the default cube? can u add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: Looks like a weird bug mentioned here on [Blender SE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/252369/78972), [blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/no-more-keyframes-to-jump-to-in-this-direction/602528), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/pv79nu/no_more_keyframes_to_jump_to_in_this_direction/). Restarting the pc seems to help :))